# Как написать парсинг apache access.log с результатом в JSON файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, логирование

Мне необходимо написать код для парсинга acccess.log и скомпилировать результаты в результирующем JSON файле. Данный файл должен содержать следующий вывод:

1. 10 самых часто встречающихся запросов
2. Помимо IP отображаются метод, URL, статус-код, длительность запроса

Пока я только в начале своего пути и написал следующий код:

```py
import argparse
import json
import re
from collections import Counter

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Код для анализа логов')
parser.add_argument('-f', dest='logfile', action='store', default='access.log')
args = parser.parse_args()

regul_ip = (r"^(?P<ips>.*?)")    

def address_top10():
    with open(args.logfile) as file:
        for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
            try:
                ips = re.search(regul_ip, line).group()
                return Counter(ips).most_common(10)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

print(json.dumps(address_top10(), indent=4))
with open("final_log.json", "w") as jsonfile:
    json.dump(address_top10(), jsonfile, indent=4)
```

После выполнения кода вот какой вывод: ""

Что-то, видимо, забыл, только не пойму - что.

Comment: можете выложить пример "access.log" на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: access.log- это стандартный лог apache-серверов. Внутри таблица с такими записями:  109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" 7269

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Модуль Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) идеально подходит для обработки, анализа и визуализации табличных данных.

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd

url_or_file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/examples/master/Common%20Data%20Formats/apache_logs/apache_logs"

cols = ['ip','l','userid','timestamp','tz','request','status','bytes','referer','useragent']

df = pd.read_csv(url_or_file, delim_whitespace=True, names=cols).drop('l', 1)
df["timestamp"] = df["timestamp"].str.lstrip("[") + " " + df.pop("tz").str.rstrip("]")
```

получили Pandas DataFrame:

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
                 ip userid                 timestamp                   request  status   bytes                   referer                 useragent
0      83.149.9.216      -  17/May/2015:10:05:03 ...  GET /presentations/lo...     200  203023  http://semicomplete.c...  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintos...
1      83.149.9.216      -  17/May/2015:10:05:43 ...  GET /presentations/lo...     200  171717  http://semicomplete.c...  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintos...
2      83.149.9.216      -  17/May/2015:10:05:47 ...  GET /presentations/lo...     200   26185  http://semicomplete.c...  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintos...
3      83.149.9.216      -  17/May/2015:10:05:12 ...  GET /presentations/lo...     200    7697  http://semicomplete.c...  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintos...
4      83.149.9.216      -  17/May/2015:10:05:07 ...  GET /presentations/lo...     200    2892  http://semicomplete.c...  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintos...
...             ...    ...                       ...                       ...     ...     ...                       ...                       ...
9994   63.140.98.80      -  20/May/2015:21:05:28 ...  GET /blog/tags/puppet...     200   14872  http://www.semicomple...  Tiny Tiny RSS/1.11 (h...
9995   63.140.98.80      -  20/May/2015:21:05:50 ...  GET /blog/geekery/sol...     200   10756                         -  Tiny Tiny RSS/1.11 (h...
9996  66.249.73.135      -  20/May/2015:21:05:00 ...  GET /?flav=atom HTTP/1.1     200   32352                         -  Mozilla/5.0 (compatib...
9997    180.76.6.56      -  20/May/2015:21:05:56 ...  GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1     200       -                         -  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows ...
9998   46.105.14.53      -  20/May/2015:21:05:15 ...  GET /blog/tags/puppet...     200   14872                         -  UniversalFeedParser/4...

[9999 rows x 8 columns]
```

теперь можно анализировать его как угодно, например показать 10 самых часто встречающихся запросов:

```
In [22]: df["request"].value_counts().iloc[:10]
Out[22]:
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1                    747
GET /style2.css HTTP/1.1                     531
GET /reset.css HTTP/1.1                      524
GET /images/jordan-80.png HTTP/1.1           521
GET /images/web/2009/banner.png HTTP/1.1     504
GET /blog/tags/puppet?flav=rss20 HTTP/1.1    488
GET /?flav=rss20 HTTP/1.1                    217
GET /projects/xdotool/ HTTP/1.1              208
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1                     156
GET / HTTP/1.1                               151
Name: request, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Панда - несомненно полезное решение, но мне нужно сделать парсер именно с помощью модуля аrgparse

Comment: @Ник, и что же вам мешает прикрутить к данному решению  парсинг  аргументов командной строки при помощи argparse? Или вы собрались парсить Apache логи при помощи argparse?

Comment: Честно говоря, слабо представляю, как это можно сделать. Я новичок в питоне, а задачка как бы уже уровня повыше чем бегинер.

Comment: Вопрос был о том как парсить Apache логи, я на него ответил и привёл протестированное решение. Если у вас возник новый вопрос, например о том как пользоваться модулем argparse, то откройте новый SO вопрос.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)